# slide down background transition

Tags: html, css

i am trying to get the background color to change on hover. [Something like this](http://jsfiddle.net/as5ZU/).
I have tried various approaches but cannot get it to work, presumably it is the way my CSS and HTML is set up. I cannot figure out why it is not working, as it should be easy to implement

Please see code below.

**CSS**

```
.image-container {
    position: relative;
}
.image-container .after {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    margin: auto;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: none;
    color: #FFF;
    background-size: 100% 200%;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, red 50%, black 50%);
    -webkit-transition: background-position 1s;
   -moz-transition: background-position 1s;
    transition: background-position 1s;
}
.image-container .after p {
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 26px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 300;
    line-height: 300px;
    height: 300px;
}
.image-container:hover .after {
    display: block;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    background-position: 0 -100%; 
}

[class*='col-'] {
    float: left;
}
.col-1-3 {
  width: 33.33%;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="col-1-3 image-container">
    <img class="portrait-image geysir" src="images/geysir.jpg">
    <div class="after">GEYSIR</div>
</div>
```

Comment: What's wrong with the working fiddle you supplied?

Comment: Where is `transition` ?

Comment: @Gofilord that working fiddle isn't mine. I can't get it to work on mine

Comment: Yours isn't even trying to accomplish what the fiddle was. Did you look at it's code? It has a background twice in height with a strict gradient, and on hover it changes the position of the background with a transition to show a different color. Where is your attempt at that?

Comment: @Gofilord i had done that already, but it wasn't working. I have added back in my most recent attempt. Please see updated question

Comment: I used your code in a separate fiddle and it's unusable. http://jsfiddle.net/as5ZU/
Set up something that illustrates actual problem you have.

Comment: @Senthe that is what i was hoping someone may be able to see why? i don't know why its not worked as i tried to implement what that jsfiddle achieves

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `background` declaration on the hover. It's overriding all the other backgrounds you declared previously.

```
.image-container:hover .after {
    display: block;
    background-position: 0 -100%; 
}
```

It should then work.

Comment: unfortunately not! i think there is a bigger problem with my css! perhaps this cannot be done inside an absolutely positioned element.

Comment: What happens exactly? Can you supply a fiddle with your own example?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the given fiddle, I would use a transparent .png image as a second overlapping element like that. Not sure if that's your intention...

```css
.container{
  position:relative;
}
.box {
    width: 400px; height: 200px;
    background-size: 100% 200%;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, red 50%, black 50%);
    -webkit-transition: background-position 1s;
    -moz-transition: background-position 1s;
    transition: background-position 1s;
}

.box:hover {
    background-position: 0 -100%;
}
.geysir{
  position:absolute;
  top:0px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <img class="portrait-image geysir" src="http://cdn.mysitemyway.com/etc-mysitemyway/icons/legacy-previews/icons-256/high-resolution-dark-blue-denim-jeans-icons-arrows/008776-high-resolution-dark-blue-denim-jeans-icon-arrows-hand-pointer1-right.png">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to have the background, including the text slide in from the top on hover? In which case you would be better transitioning a bottom move like this:

```
.image-container {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.image-container .after {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: black;
    -webkit-transition: bottom 1s;
   -moz-transition: bottom 1s;
    transition: bottom 1s;
}
.image-container:hover .after {
    bottom: 0;
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n41atLaf/)

If you're looking to have your text appear on a red background that shifts to black, try using a combination of the above with what you were using. Avoid using display: none/block as this stops the transistion from functioning.

```
.image-container {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.image-container .after {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    color: #fff;    
    background-size: 100% 200%;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, red 50%, black 50%);
    -webkit-transition: background-position 2s;
   -moz-transition: background-position 2s;
    transition: background-position: 2s;
}
.image-container:hover .after {
    bottom: 0;
    background-position: 0 -100%; 
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n41atLaf/1/)